# How can i subscribe to multiple topics when programming in C++

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I want to subscribe to multiple topics i am trying the following code but doesn't work.
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include <Robot_Position/Num.h>

float vk;
float v ;
float va;
float a;

void chatterCallback(const Robot_Position::Num::ConstPtr& msg1) {

```
    float v1 = msg1->v1;
    float vr = msg1->vr;
 va=(v1+vr)/2;}
```

void chatterCallback2(const Robot_Position::Num::ConstPtr& msg2) {

```
    float a1 = msg2->a1;
float a2 = msg2->a2;
a=(a1+a2)/2;}
```

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

```
ros::init(argc, argv, "robot_position");
ros::NodeHandle n;
ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe<Robot_Position::Num>("Encoder_vel", 1000, chatterCallback);

ros::NodeHandle n;
ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe<Robot_Position::Num>("Accelerometer", 1000, chatterCallback2);
ros::spin();

return 0;
```

}

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/230225/how-can-i-subscribe-to-multiple-topics-when-programming-in-c++/) by [Knowledge](https://answers.ros.org/users/26126/knowledge/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2016-03-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please don't post code that doesn't even compile. You should call the ros::init only once and you need to use ros::spin() so that the program does not terminate immediately.

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2016-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Knowledge](https://answers.ros.org/users/26126/knowledge/) on 2016-03-27**:
Please can you give an example how should i do this?

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2016-03-27**:
a) call ros::init once
b) call ros::spin() after you set up the second subscriber

**Comment by [Knowledge](https://answers.ros.org/users/26126/knowledge/) on 2016-03-27**:
I edited the complete code i used. The following error is occuring.
ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe<Robot_Position::Num>("Encoder_vel", 1000, chatterCallback);
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/position_node.dir/src/position_node.cpp.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/saad/jade_workspace/sandbox

**Comment by [Augusto Luis Ballardini](https://answers.ros.org/users/234/augusto-luis-ballardini/) on 2016-03-27**:
Follow the wiki example [Writing the Subscriber Node](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29#roscpp_tutorials.2BAC8-Tutorials.2BAC8-WritingPublisherSubscriber.Writing_the_Subscriber_Node) and instead of one single callback write as many as you want.

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2016-03-27**:
You should probably start by learning C++ before your dive into ROS. You are not allowed to have several variables with the same name.